# Query the associated table (without losing my hair)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Ok, so here's the deal .. this should be simple, and I'm probably screwing up some sort of syntax somewhere:

---

I've got a `Charge` model that has a `belongs_to` relationship with a `Card`.

I'd like to retrieve all `Charges` that belong to any `Card` with the `name` "John Doe".

I've tried the following, but it's not working like it should (probably because I'm screwing the syntax):

```
Charge.where(card: [name: "John Doe"])
```

Help a brother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@FloatingRock: Just try this:

```
Charge.joins(:card).where(cards: { name: 'John Doe' })
```

As per your requirment, first we need to join `Charge` with `Card` and then apply a condition. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks .. works! I'm curious, what would I need to do to add a condition for `cards` based on an attribute of `Charge` (e.g. `Charge.joins(:card).where(cards: { name: Charge.name })` -- which doesn't work )

Comment: You're missing a closing paranthesis on your "where" method, but otherwise this looks good.

Comment: @FloatingRock: I didn't get your question.

Comment: @Kuldeep essentially, the question is what if I want to join the two tables on something other than the `id`?

Comment: @FloatingRock: Do you want this join to be fixed or dynamic? If fixed, then you can use `foreign_key` and `primary_key` option with the association.

Comment: @Kuldeep it'll probably be dynamic then

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I'll post it in case you're new to Rails and didn't know. If you have the Card object already, you can just get a list of its charges like so:

```
card.charges
```

This is also much safer, because you don't want to assume that two cards with the same name belong to the same person.

You may have already known this, but it'll be here for others who might need it.